# JSON string Deserialization into C# List

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am trying to deserialize the JSON String from WCF Service into C# List which is showing null output.

**WCF Service**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
)]
public String getuserSite(String UserCode)
{
    string s = "";
    {
        _ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            _dbObj = new Database();
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB"].ToString() == "S")
            {
                string[] _paramNames = { "@UserCode" };
                object[] _paramvalue = { UserCode };
                _ds = _dbObj.GetDatasetProc("getuserSite", _paramNames, _paramvalue);
            }
            else
            {
                string[] _paramNames = { "UserCode" };
                object[] _paramvalue = { UserCode };
                _ds = _dbObj.GetDatasetProc("getuserSite", _paramNames, _paramvalue);
            }
            return **GetJSONString**(_ds, "Sites");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            _dbObj.Close();
        }    
}
```

GetJSONString Method returns **JSON String**

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    public static string GetJSONString(DataSet Ds, String Name)
    {
        DataTable Dt = Ds.Tables[0];
        if (Name != "")
        {
            Dt.TableName = Name;
        }
        string[] StrDc = new string[Dt.Columns.Count];
        string HeadStr = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {

            StrDc[i] = Dt.Columns[i].Caption;

            HeadStr += "\"" + StrDc[i] + "\" : \"" + StrDc[i] + i.ToString() + "¾" + "\",";
        }

        HeadStr = HeadStr.Substring(0, HeadStr.Length - 1);

        StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (Name != "")
        {
            Sb.Append("{\"" + Dt.TableName + "\" : [");
        }
        else
        {
            Sb.Append("[");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string TempStr = HeadStr;
            Sb.Append("{");

            for (int j = 0; j < Dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                TempStr = TempStr.Replace(Dt.Columns[j] + j.ToString() + "¾", Dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br>").Replace("\r", "<br>").Replace("\n", "<br>").Replace("\"",""));
            }

            if (i < Dt.Rows.Count - 1) { Sb.Append(TempStr + "},"); } else { Sb.Append(TempStr + "}"); };
        }

        Sb = new StringBuilder(Sb.ToString().Substring(0, Sb.ToString().Length));
        if (Name != "")
        {
            Sb.Append("]}");
        }
        else
        {
            Sb.Append("]");
        }
              return Sb.ToString();    

    }
```

**Json String Output**

```
"\"{\\\"Sites\\\" : [{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"SIERRA India\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"1\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"SIERRA Dubai\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"24\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"SIERRA Malaysia\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"99\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"SIERRA US\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"100\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"Mars India\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"110\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"???\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"151\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"turkey\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"2299\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"SIERRA Infosys\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"2331\\\"},{\\\"EQ_DESC\\\" : \\\"Infosys\\\",\\\"EQ_CODE\\\" : \\\"2338\\\"}]}\""
```

**C# Class (Model)**

```
 public class Site
{
 public string EQ_DESC { get; set; }
 public string EQ_CODE { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
 public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}
```

**Now Deserialising json into List**

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        /* Deserializing json data from service */
                        var jsoncontent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        string s = jsoncontent.ToString();

                    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(s);
```

**Output :**

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(s);
```

** We have tried this earlier, but it returns null **

```
 var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<site>>(s);
```

The above code results retun Null.

Kindly suggest me to solve the issue.

Thanks

Venkatesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string output is a `List<Site>`. The `RootObject` class is not a `List<Site>` but contains a property `Sites` of type `List<Site>`. You should try something like this :

**First solution :**

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Site>>(s);
```

**Second solution :**

Modify your RootObject like this :

```
public class RootObject : List<Site>
{
  //Whatever you want
}
```

And using the deserializer like this :

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(s);
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT** : This is something to test

Why did you return a JSON string ? I mean, if you use the serializer, you could specify your server to convert result into JSON string automatically then retrieve the stream inside the request and deserialize as you have already done. Let me show what works on my machine :

**FIRST** : Your service contrat interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceContract
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
       List<Site> getuserSite(String UserCode);
}
```

**SECOND** : Service contract implementation

```
public class ServiceContract : IServiceContract
{
   public List<Site> getuserSite(String UserCode)
   {
      //Do whatever you want that return a List<Site>
   }
}
```

**THIRD** : Your Model

```
[DataContract]
public class Site
{
   [DataMember]
    public string EQ_DESC { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
    public string EQ_CODE { get; set; }
}
```

**FOURTH** : On your client side after referencing your data contract

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{

      /* Deserializing json data from service */

      DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Site>));
      var result= deserializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
}
```

In result you will have your List corresponding to the JSON deserialized response. I hope yould find a way to make it work in your code. Feel free to contact me if needed.

Comment: We have tried your suggestions but failed to convert the JSON String to List collection and it returns null. Kindly check the updated code.

Comment: @user3167868 Did the second solution worked for you ?

Comment: yes. Second solution worked out very well.Thanks for your kind help

Comment: @Venkatesh Glad it helped. Could you please indicate the answer as the solution and/or vote for it please ? Thank you